# Maven throwing SAML Statement error message

Tags: java, maven

I am working on Maven and I get error as shown below. I tried checking deployment assembly and build path but I am not getting any hint on what the system is complaining about. I also made sure I cleaned tomcat directory and cleaned the project. I would appreciate any help on it

```
 Jan 20, 2020 12:11:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve
 invoke SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [cas] in context with
 path [/URL] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested
 exception is
 org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutionException:
 Exception thrown executing
 org.springframework.webflow.action.ViewFactoryActionAdapter@2def1006
 in state 'viewServiceErrorView' of flow 'login' -- action execution
 attributes were 'map[[empty]]'] with root cause
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.opensaml.SAMLStatement   at
 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
    at
 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1139)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)  at
 java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)    at
 java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)   at
 java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.
```

Comment: Could you please show us your code (Not the exception only) and elaborate more on your question (Let me know your scenario)?

Comment: when I send event output in spring webflow, spring webflow is throwing this exception. It is related to library conflict in maven but I am not able to pinpoint the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the system was complaining I was missing opensaml jar.

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
 <artifactId>opensaml</artifactId>
 <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

System was unable to download the jar from maven repo. I manually updated the jar in my local and it worked fine.